# Same size for 2 Imageviews, one is wrap_content

Tags: android, layout, imageview, size

I'm looking for a way to get my two imageviews on the same size.

Imageview A is : `width: match_parent
height: wrap_content
scaleType: centerInside
adjustViewBounds: true`

Imageview B is : 
`width: match_parent
height: wrap_content`

And ImageView B is over Imageview A. But, the height of A is determinated by his content. So I would like that my ImageView B be at the same size than A.

I tried this : (In my RecyclerView adapter).

```
final ImageView v2 = holder.miniatureVideo;
            final ImageView shadow2 = holder.shadow;
            v2.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    shadow2.getLayoutParams().height = v2.getHeight();
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.LayoutParams) shadow2.getLayoutParams();
                    params.height = v2.getHeight();
                    shadow2.setLayoutParams(params);
                }
            });
```

But there is a little delay, before it is correctly resize. And sometimes I have to scroll to make it resized.

Thanks

Comment: You can try hiding tImageView A by setting visibility to invisible, calculate it's height and set that height to your ImageView B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try `RelativeLayout` ?

like this:

```
  <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_a"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/imageA"/>

        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/image_a"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/image_a"
                android:src="@drawable/imageB"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was expecting, and it works.Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
int finalHeight, finalWidth;
final ImageView imageView1= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.scaled_image);
ViewTreeObserver vto = imageView1.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
     public boolean onPreDraw() {
        imageView1.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
        finalHeight = imageView1.getMeasuredHeight();
        finalWidth = imageView1.getMeasuredWidth();
        return true;
     }
});
```

First get height of ImageOne as above.. Then Set it to ImageTwo as below

```
 android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = imageView2.getLayoutParams();
 layoutParams.width = finalWidth;
 layoutParams.height = finalHeight ;
 imageView2.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```